# How do I set ORDER BY in SQL query to a value depending by the SQL query itself?

Tags: sql

Imagine an auction (ebay auction, for example). You create an auction, set the start bidding value, let's say, 5 dollars. This gets stored as a minimal bid value to the `auctions` table.At this point, the **current** bid value of this auction is **5 dollars**.

Now, if someone bids to your auction, let's say, 10 dollars, this gets stored to the `bids` table.At this point, the **current** bid value of this auction is **10 dollars**.

Now let's imagine you want to retrieve 5 cheapest auctions. You will write a query like this:

```
SELECT
`auction_id`,
`auction_startPrice`,
MAX(bids.bid_price) as `bid_price`
FROM
`auctions`
LEFT JOIN `bids` ON `auctions`.`auction_id`=`bids`.`bid_belongs_to_auction`
GROUP BY `auction_id`
LIMIT 5
```

Pretty simple, and it works! But now you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query. The problem is, however, that we want to `ORDER BY` **either** by `auctions.auction_startPrice` **or** by `bid_price`, depending on **whichever of this is higher**, as explained in the first paragraphs.

Can this be understood? I know how to do this using 2 queries, but I am hoping it can be done with 1 query.

Thanks!

EDIT: Just a further explanation to help you imagine the problem. If I set `ORDER BY auction_startPrice ASC`, then I will get 5 auctions with their lowest initial bid price, but what if there are already bids placed on those auctions? Then their current lowest price is equal to those bids, NOT to the start price, therefore my query is wrong.

Comment: But as bid_price is always higher or equal to auction_startPrice, why not to just order by bid_price? (or isnull(bidprice,auction_startPrice) if there isn´t any bid yet(

Comment: bid_price is not present if no bids are placed yet, so I cannot order it by bid price, as in some cases it is NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `auction_id`,
  `auction_startPrice`,
  `bid_price`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        `auction_id`,
        `auction_startPrice`,
        MAX(bids.bid_price) as `bid_price`,
        IF(MAX(bids.bid_price)>`auction_startPrice`,
           MAX(bids.bid_price),
           `auction_startPrice`) higherPrice
    FROM
    `auctions`
    LEFT JOIN `bids` ON `auctions`.`auction_id`=`bids`.`bid_belongs_to_auction`
    GROUP BY `auction_id`
) X
order by higherPrice desc
LIMIT 5;
```

Note:

1. In the inner query, an extra column is created, named 'higherPrice'
2. The IF function compares the `MAX(bid_price)` column against the `startprice`, and only if the Max-bid is not null (implicitly required in comparison) and greater than start price, then the Max-bid becomes the value in the `higherPrice` column.  Otherwise, it will contain the start price.
3. The outer query merely makes use of the columns from the inner query, ordering by the `higherPrice`

Comment: this looks interesting and from the first glance, I think you understood my problem. I'm going to try it out right away and report back soon.

Comment: Sir, I'm so sad I don't understand how you did this, but it works perfectly. Thanks a lot, hopefully I will get it one day too :)

Comment: So what's the ``X`` doing there? What does it mean? Is like like a short for ``FROM () as X`` ? Just a placeholder to contain the result?

Comment: @RiMMER - exactly. `(.. some query..) AS X` (the word AS is optional) means that you can now reference the data produced by the query as if it were a table named "`X`"

Comment: It's just the name of the subquery.  If you look at the profiler, it makes a temp table with the "inner" query and then queries from with with the "outter" query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which database you're using but look at this [example](http://www.extremeexperts.com/sql/articles/CASEinORDER.aspx):
http://www.extremeexperts.com/sql/articles/CASEinORDER.aspx

```
SELECT
`auction_id`,
`auction_startPrice`,
MAX(bids.bid_price) as `bid_price`
FROM
`auctions`
LEFT JOIN `bids` ON `auctions`.`auction_id`=`bids`.`bid_belongs_to_auction`
GROUP BY `auction_id`
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `auction_startPrice` > isnull(MAX(bids.bid_price),0) then `auction_startPrice` else MAX(bids.bid_price) end
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: You probably need to handle the case where MAX(bids.bid_price) is NULL.

Comment: You're right, I thought about that but didn't add it to my answer because I was lazy.  I'll add now.

Comment: Or maybe `WHEN MAX(bids.bid_price) >= auction_startPrice` which will also fail when MAX(bids.bid_prices) is NULL...